# Why is my CapsuleCollider2D in Unity not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to shoot a Meteorit. My Capsule Collider of the Bullet has the Trigger on and the Meteorit have an edge
Collider with Trigger is off. But my Collider didn't work. This is my Code for the Bullet:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class bullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int speed;       

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = transform.up * speed;
    }   

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        Debug.Log(other.name);    
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it the other way round (bullet non-trigger, meteor trigger)?

Comment: Yes but I didn’t works

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your editor ? Nothing seems off with this script

Answer (score 0):

- These colliding functions need at least one RigidBody attached to one of the game objects to work. You should attach a RigidBody component to one of them. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html
- Also, check `Layer Collision Matrix`. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Physics2DManager.html

Comment: @Timon have you checked `Layer Collision Matrix` in physics settings?

Comment: @Timon add some images of Rigid body and Collider components so we can see the properties of them.

Comment: Here two links for the images for the bullet and the Meteorit